# How to get SharePoint file creator name using SharePoint object model?

Tags: 2010

How can I get following information about a SharePoint document.

```
* Created By
* Last modified by
```

I need to find this meta data information using SharePoint object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value by first of all getting the reference of the SPItem of an existing item in the SharePoint library and then doing item["CreatedBy"].Tostring() to get field value .

Note: This Created By will provide you to the SharePoint formated name of the user who uploaded the file on SharePoint and not the one who created it using MS Office.

Answer (score 0):

The [SPBuiltInFieldID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid_members.aspx) class contains ids for most of the built in fields.

In your case I believe Author and Editor are the 2 fields you need.